# Fallback for CSS variable assigned to a CSS variable

Tags: css, postcss, css-variables

When it comes to features like CSS Custom Properties, I use [postcss-preset-env](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env) in order to have fallback definitions printed for older browsers like IE 11.

So, for example if I have:

```
:root {
    --col-light: #fff;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--col-light);
}
```

the output will be:

```
:root {
    --col-light: #fff;
}

body {
    color: #fff; // the fallback value
    color: var(--col-light);
}
```

However, when I assign a CSS variable to another CSS variable and use the second one as a value for a property, then the fallback feature does not work as expected – it's not passing the first variable's value (#fff) through the second variable to the property. So if I have this:

```
:root {
    --col-light: #fff;
    --main-background: var(--col-light);
}

body {
    background-color: var(--main-background);
}
```

The output will be like so:

```
:root {
    --col-light: #fff;
    --main-background: #fff; // a fallback value where it's not needed
    --main-background: var(--col-light);
}

body {
    color: var(--main-background);
}
```

The outcome makes the fallback feature useless.

So here comes the question:
**Is there a way to make the fallback feature working as expected?**

Comment: If I understand well, the issue is with the code you are using? if yes I think you should raise a bug or something so they can correct this behavior

Comment: Yeah, I raised an issue (https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env/issues/72) but I was also hoping that someone would have experienced such case and might know a workaround.

Comment: by the way what is the purpose of defining a variable using another? in this particular case it's useless ... do you have any relevant case where it's needed? based on that we can provide a solution

Comment: @Temani Afif: You can have a color scheme with just a handful of swatches, and see the same swatch being reused across different UI elements. For example, in this case, a light color might be used for a few different things, one or more of which might be background colors with unique purposes. It's just an extra level of abstraction to make code a little more readable or semantic to developers, I guess. I see this a lot in XAML themes, for example (and in fact have made my own themes that follow this exact pattern).

Comment: I usually create some sort of "Registry of colors" where I define variables for every color used in my project. Based on this registry I define another set of variables (as another layer above) used as different roles used in the platform. For example, I have a registry variable as follows: --reg-color-red: #f00 and based on it I have two role variables as follows: --role-validation-error: var(--reg-color-red) and --role-state-active: var(--reg-color-red). Both role variables have different use but they both depend on one color.

Comment: So if I would like to change the hex of the color itself at some point I'll just do this to the registry variable. And if I want just to change the color used for validation errors to another one from my registry I just make the change to the role variable.

Comment: what if you try this : https://jsfiddle.net/76zh2kpj/ ... the orde isn't important but probably postcss will behave differently

Comment: Nope. It's not working. Never mind. :) Thanks anyway.